# XUnit and Pact Verification Unable to see out for pact verification failure

Tags: xunit, pact-net

I am following the PactNet workshop example given at https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v3/

I have no issues with Consumer side code. All tests are passing and a pact interactions file is being generated.

However, the tests are failing on Provider side when trying to verify the generated pact file. The problem is I can't see detailed error message why the verification is failed. See the attached console output
[XUnit Verification failure output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EeQL.png)

My provider tests code is same as on the described at https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v3/blob/master/Provider/tests/ProductTest.cs

And my Provider test .csproj has same NuGet packages as given in the workshop example

```css
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.4" />
<PackageReference Include="PactNet" Version="4.0.0-beta" />
<PackageReference Include="PactNet.Native" Version="0.1.0-beta" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Can someone please help what I am missing here to see the detailed error output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the 'Outputers' property of the 'PactVerifierConfig' instance.
Here's the code from the [same link](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-workshop-dotnet-core-v3/blob/master/Provider/tests/ProductTest.cs) you provided

```
    var config = new PactVerifierConfig
    {
        // NOTE: We default to using a ConsoleOutput, however xUnit 2 does not capture the console output,
        // so a custom outputter is required.
        Outputters = new List<IOutput>
        {
            new XUnitOutput(_outputHelper)
        }
    };
```